# mysqldump stopped working with conversion to MariaDB - set-gtid-purged=OFF issue?

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

I am on a shared server (webhostinghub) and run a nightly CRON job to back up my mySQl InnoDB database. The CRON job runs a php script which in turn issues a `mysqldump` command via `passthrough()` as follows;

```
$return = -1;
$command = "mysqldump -h localhost -u server_user -ppassword --add-drop-table --quick --set-gtid-purged=OFF server_database > ./backup/backup-2018-02-19.sql"; 

passthrough($command, $return);    // note: I just added the $return parameter to see what it is returning which is `7` => non zero tells me there is some error but there is no further info I can find.
```

The script was working for years without error and recently started creating zero byte files.

I notice from phpMyAdmin that:

```
Server type: MariaDB
Server version: 10.2.11-MariaDB-log - MariaDB Server
Protocol version: 10
```

I don't remember being on `MariaDB` and it is obvious my provider switched me over without mentioning it (thanks webhostinghub) and this is the issue. I know they are supposed to be 99% compatible, but is this the 1%?

I removed the `--set-gtid-purged=OFF` parameter and the backup "appears" to have worked (I have not validated the data, but the file now has data).

I can't remember why I added the `--set-gtid-purged=OFF` parameter and what it does is not completely obvious to me. I know it is for Global Transaction Identifier’s (GTID’s) but am not sure if I use these. I do not "replicate" but want my exports and imports to keep unique primary ids. I import into a mysql database on my localhost.

I would appreciate any help in determining the equivalent `mysqldump` command for the `MariaDB` database and what to look out for when importing into my localhost `mysql` database

Thanks

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_set-gtid-purged

Comment: @Mike - Thanks for the link to the docs. It helps make it clear that its an option I don't really need because I am not replicating.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implementation of [GTID-based replication in MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/gtid/) is completely different from MySQL's, so the logic which supports it in tools such as `mysqldump` is also incompatible. `set-gtid-purged` option in MySQL's version of `mysqldump` sets a variable which doesn't exist and would have no meaning in MariaDB, so the option does not exist, either. If you don't use replication in general and GTID in particular, you can just remove the option from the command line, the rest should work identically. It should have no effect on primary keys, if that's what you mean by primary ids.

"Almost complete compatibility" on option/syntax level between MariaDB and MySQL is true for release lines **up to and including 5.5**. Starting from MariaDB 10.0 and MySQL 5.6, there are noticeable differences.

Here is a [list of known incompatibilities between MariaDB and MySQL](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/). It might be incomplete, but it should cover the most part.

Loading a dump of MySQL server into MariaDB server should work, unless MySQL server was using some syntax or features that MariaDB either does not have or has in a different form. Loading a dump made by MySQL's version of `mysqldump` into MariaDB server might cause problems, for example if it sets variables which MariaDB does not have (such as `@@global.gtid_purged` controlled by `set-gtid-purged`, there can be more). In this case, manual editing of the dump might be needed.

Comment: I likely used this switch (years ago) from a SO example . Since I don't completely understand `GTID-based replication` its likely that I misunderstood its relevance in my situation. Thanks for verifying the incompatibility and explaining why I don't need it. (Yes I meant primary keys).

Comment: I've added a link to the list of known incompatibilities for the reference. To a big extent it's maintained based on the input from the community, additions are appreciated.